# Getting id names with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If I had the text:

```
text = '<span id="foo"></span> <div id="bar"></div>'
```

with text that can change (that might not have any ids), how could I use BeautifulSoup to get the id names regardless of tag name(returning ['foo','bar']).  I'm not that experienced to BeautifulSoup and have been confused on doing this task.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to get tag with id attributes then return values of id attributes to string e.g.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
text = '<span id="foo"></span> <div id="bar"></div>'
pool = BeautifulSoup(text)
result = []
for tag in pool.findAll(True,{'id':True}) :
    result.append(tag['id'])
```

and result

```
>>> result
[u'foo', u'bar']
```

Comment: great! answer not easy to come  by otherwise